# Shortcut for solving $165x \equiv 100 \pmod{285}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Shortcut for solving $165x \equiv 100 \pmod{285}$

The usual way is to check values of x, but if a shortcut is needed then it is needed to convert the equation into an equality:
$165x = 100 + 285k, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$

This brings up a linear Diophantine equation (LDE) with $\gcd$ on r.h.s. 
$165x -285k = 100$
=> $33x - 57k = 20$

Comparison with the standard form for LDE : $ax + by = c$ 
 brings up the values of coefficients as : $a = 33, b = -57, c = 20$, with the values $x,y$ found by EEA.

Stuck here, please help.

Comment: This has no solution.  Note that $3$ divides both $285$ and $165$ but it does not divide $100$.

Comment: Since $\gcd(165, 285) = 15$ you are not going to get an $x$ that will give you $100$

Comment: Yes, r.h.s. in L.D.E. has to be a multiple of the g.c.d., i.e., here of the form : $15k, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of Diophantine’s equation,
\begin{align}
-57  & = (-2)\times33 + 9\\
33 & = 3\times 9 + 6 \\
9 & = 1\times 6 + 3 \\
6 & = 2\times 3 + 0
\end{align}

Since $20$ is not divisible by $3$, we have no solution.